# Excel VBA to parse JSON out of Google Maps API

Tags: vba, json, excel, google-maps

Some code that I wrote and broke into 5 separate questions on stack overflow.  Some guy wanted to query Google Maps receive some JSON and then for each result found within that JSON do another query.  I didn;t quite understand what he wanted at first and so actually there is some superfluous code here but I thought it would be useful to park my findings as to good practices for parsing JSON.

I use XHR requests.   To parse the JSON, I use the ScriptControl.  I have used this before.  I have also seen a number of stack overflow questions which advocate third party libraries and I was puzzled by this.  They all seem to take a mini-script approach of adding some javascript code to the script engine and calling it is cool but perhaps used too widely when there is a native solution available.

The key finding here is the use of VBA's CallByName function which can be used to query a JScriptTypeInfo Object Instance i.e. that which comes out of ScriptControl's Eval method.

CallByName can be used to get a member value; it can be used to query length of an array; it can be used to access elements of an array all with any javascript.  Further I found some hasOwnProperty() method which allows defensive programming, so call this in cases where one thinks a member is missing.  I also found some debugging sugar to stringify variables.

Look for some code review here.  Will entertain suggestions, looking for best practice because in future looking to build J2EE application with REST interfaces that will use JSON and was planning to use Excel VBA as a debugging front end tool.  Thanks.

```
'Tools->References->
'Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'Microsoft Script Control 1.0;  {0E59F1D2-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}; C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msscript.ocx
'Microsoft Xml, v6.0

Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Private Const sKEYNAME As String = "Server key 1"

'Public Const sKEY As String = "Your key goes here and uncomment"

Private Const sSEVENOAKS_PLACEID As String = "ChIJwd9bXUyt2EcRYv6GY0JRnCw"   'Place ID: ChIJwd9bXUyt2EcRYv6GY0JRnCw Sevenoaks , Sevenoaks, Kent, UK


Private Const sSEVENOAKS_LATITUDE_LONGITUDE As String = "51.2724,0.1909"    '51.2724° N, 0.1909° E


Private Function GetScriptEngine() As ScriptControl
    Static soScriptEngine As ScriptControl
    If soScriptEngine Is Nothing Then
        Set soScriptEngine = New ScriptControl
        soScriptEngine.Language = "JScript"

        soScriptEngine.AddCode GetJavaScriptLibrary("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js")
        soScriptEngine.AddCode "function getKeyValues(jsonObj) { " & _
                              " var dictionary = new ActiveXObject(""Scripting.Dictionary""); " & _
                              " var keys = new Array(); for (var i in jsonObj) { dictionary.add(i,jsonObj[i]); }; return dictionary; } "

        soScriptEngine.AddCode "function setKeyValue(jsonObj, key, newItem) { jsonObj[key]=newItem; return jsonObj; }"
        soScriptEngine.AddCode "function toVBString(jsonObj) { return JSON.stringify(jsonObj); }"
        soScriptEngine.AddCode "function overrideToString(jsonObj) { jsonObj.toString = function() { return JSON.stringify(this); } }"
    End If
    Set GetScriptEngine = soScriptEngine
End Function

Private Function GetJavaScriptLibrary(ByVal sURL As String) As String

    Dim xHTTPRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set xHTTPRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    xHTTPRequest.Open "GET", sURL, False
    xHTTPRequest.send
    GetJavaScriptLibrary = xHTTPRequest.responseText

End Function

Private Function DecodeJsonString(ByVal JsonString As String) As Object
    Dim oScriptEngine As ScriptControl
    Set oScriptEngine = GetScriptEngine

    Set DecodeJsonString = oScriptEngine.Eval("(" + JsonString + ")")

    Call oScriptEngine.Run("overrideToString", DecodeJsonString) '* this gives JSON rendering instead of "[object Object]"

End Function

Private Function GetJSONPrimitive(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal sKey As String, Optional vDefaultValue As Variant) As Variant
    Dim vRet As Variant

    If obj.hasOwnProperty(sKey) Then
        vRet = VBA.CallByName(obj, sKey, VbGet)
    Else
        vRet = vDefaultValue
    End If
    GetJSONPrimitive = vRet
End Function


Private Function GetJSONObject(ByVal obj As Object, ByVal sKey As String) As Object
    Dim objReturn As Object
    If obj.hasOwnProperty(sKey) Then

        Set objReturn = VBA.CallByName(obj, sKey, VbGet)
        Call GetScriptEngine.Run("overrideToString", objReturn) '* this gives JSON rendering instead of "[object Object]"

    End If
    Set GetJSONObject = objReturn
End Function

Private Function TestAll() As Boolean
    Debug.Assert TestPlaceDetails
    Debug.Assert TestNearbySearch
    Debug.Assert TestAutoComplete
    Debug.Assert BigTest
    Debug.Assert EvenBiggerTest
    Debug.Assert TestTextSearch 'biggest of all
    TestAll = True
End Function


Private Function BigTest() As Boolean

    Dim dicPlacesWithPlaceIds As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicPlacesWithPlaceIds = AutoComplete(sKey, "Sevenoaks")

    ReDim v(1 To dicPlacesWithPlaceIds.Count + 1, 1 To 2)
    v(1, 1) = "Place": v(1, 2) = "Lat, Long"
    Dim lLoop As Long
    For lLoop = 1 To dicPlacesWithPlaceIds.Count

        Dim sPlace As String
        sPlace = dicPlacesWithPlaceIds.Keys()(lLoop - 1)

        Dim sPlaceID As String
        sPlaceID = dicPlacesWithPlaceIds.Items()(lLoop - 1)

        Dim dicPlaceDetails As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set dicPlaceDetails = PlaceDetails(sKey, sPlaceID)

        v(lLoop + 1, 1) = sPlace
        v(lLoop + 1, 2) = dicPlaceDetails.Items()(0)

    Next

    'Stop
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(dicPlacesWithPlaceIds.Count + 1, 2)).Value2 = v
    BigTest = True
End Function



Private Function EvenBiggerTest() As Boolean

    Dim dicPlacesWithPlaceIds As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicPlacesWithPlaceIds = AutoComplete(sKey, "Hamburg")

    If dicPlacesWithPlaceIds.Count > 0 Then

        Dim sTopPrediction As String
        sTopPrediction = dicPlacesWithPlaceIds.Keys()(0)

        Dim sTopPredictionPlaceId As String
        sTopPredictionPlaceId = dicPlacesWithPlaceIds.Items()(0)

        Dim dicPlaceDetails As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set dicPlaceDetails = PlaceDetails(sKey, sTopPredictionPlaceId)

        Dim sTopPredictionLocation As String
        sTopPredictionLocation = dicPlaceDetails.Item("Location")

        Dim dicNearbySearchResults As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set dicNearbySearchResults = NearbySearch(sKey, sTopPredictionLocation, 100, "post office")

        ReDim v(1 To dicNearbySearchResults.Count + 1, 1 To 5)
        v(1, 1) = "Name": v(1, 2) = "PlaceId": v(1, 3) = "Address": v(1, 4) = "Vicinity": v(1, 5) = "Type0"

        Dim lLoop As Long
        For lLoop = 1 To dicNearbySearchResults.Count

            Dim sPlaceIdLoop As String
            sPlaceIdLoop = dicNearbySearchResults.Items()(lLoop - 1)

            Set dicPlaceDetails = PlaceDetails(sKey, sPlaceIdLoop)

            v(lLoop + 1, 1) = dicNearbySearchResults.Keys()(lLoop - 1)
            v(lLoop + 1, 2) = sPlaceIdLoop
            v(lLoop + 1, 3) = dicPlaceDetails.Item("Address")
            If dicPlaceDetails.Exists("Vicinity") Then
                v(lLoop + 1, 4) = dicPlaceDetails.Item("Vicinity")
            End If
            If dicPlaceDetails.Exists("Type0") Then
                v(lLoop + 1, 5) = dicPlaceDetails.Item("Type0")
            End If

        Next

        'Stop
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Clear
        ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(dicNearbySearchResults.Count + 1, 5)).Value2 = v
    End If
    EvenBiggerTest = True
End Function


Private Function TextSearch(ByVal sAPIKey As String, ByVal sSearchQuery As String, ByRef pdicFieldOrinals As Scripting.Dictionary) As Scripting.Dictionary

    '
    'Tools->References->
    'Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim dicTextSearchResults As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicTextSearchResults = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Set pdicFieldOrinals = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim psNextPageToken As String: psNextPageToken = ""


    Do
        If psNextPageToken <> "" Then
            Application.Wait (Now() + CDate("00:00:05"))
        End If

        Dim xHTTPRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        Set xHTTPRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

        Dim sURL As String
        sURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=" & sAPIKey & "&query=" & sSearchQuery

        If psNextPageToken <> "" Then sURL = sURL & "&pagetoken=" & psNextPageToken


        xHTTPRequest.Open "GET", sURL

        xHTTPRequest.send

        While xHTTPRequest.readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Wend

        If Len(xHTTPRequest.responseText) > 0 Then
            'Debug.Print Left$(xHTTPRequest.responseText, 500)

            Dim objJSON As Object
            Set objJSON = DecodeJsonString(xHTTPRequest.responseText)

            ParseTextSearchResponse objJSON, dicTextSearchResults, pdicFieldOrinals, psNextPageToken
        End If
    Loop Until psNextPageToken = ""
    Set TextSearch = dicTextSearchResults

End Function

Private Function TestTextSearch() As Boolean
    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Clear

    Dim pdicFieldOrinals As Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim dicTextSearchResults As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicTextSearchResults = TextSearch(sKey, "london+restaurants", pdicFieldOrinals)

    Dim dicDetails As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicDetails = dicTextSearchResults.Item(dicTextSearchResults.Keys()(0))


    Dim vGrid As Variant
    vGrid = NestedDictionaryToGrid(dicTextSearchResults, pdicFieldOrinals)

    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1), ActiveSheet.Cells(dicTextSearchResults.Count + 1, pdicFieldOrinals.Count)).Value2 = vGrid
    TestTextSearch = True
End Function


Private Function ParseTextSearchResponse(ByVal objJSON As Object, _
                ByVal dicTextSearchResults As Scripting.Dictionary, ByVal dicFieldOrinals As Scripting.Dictionary, _
                ByRef psPageToken As String)

    If Not objJSON Is Nothing Then

        psPageToken = GetJSONPrimitive(objJSON, "next_page_token", "")

        Dim sStatus As String
        sStatus = GetJSONPrimitive(objJSON, "status")

        If sStatus = "OK" Then

            Dim objResults As Object
            Set objResults = GetJSONObject(objJSON, "results")

            Dim lLength As Long
            lLength = GetJSONPrimitive(objResults, "length", -1)


            Dim lLoop As Long
            For lLoop = 0 To lLength - 1

                Dim objResultLoop As Object
                Set objResultLoop = GetJSONObject(objResults, CStr(lLoop))

                Dim sName As String
                sName = GetJSONPrimitive(objResultLoop, "name")

                Dim dicKeys As Scripting.Dictionary
                Set dicKeys = GetScriptEngine.Run("getKeyValues", objResultLoop)

                Dim dicFlattenedDetails As Scripting.Dictionary
                Set dicFlattenedDetails = New Scripting.Dictionary

                Dim vKeyLoop As Variant
                For Each vKeyLoop In dicKeys.Keys

                    If Not dicFieldOrinals.Exists(vKeyLoop) Then dicFieldOrinals.Add vKeyLoop, dicFieldOrinals.Count

                    Dim vValue As Variant: vValue = Empty

                    Select Case vKeyLoop
                    Case "formatted_address", "icon", "id", "name", "permanently_closed", "place_id", "price_level", "rating", "reference":
                        vValue = VBA.CallByName(objResultLoop, vKeyLoop, VbGet)
                        dicFlattenedDetails.Add vKeyLoop, vValue
                    Case "geometry":
                        dicFlattenedDetails.Add "geometry", ExtractLatitudeAndLongitude(GetJSONObject(objResultLoop, "geometry"))
                    Case "opening_hours":
                        dicFlattenedDetails.Add "opening_hours", ExtractOpeningHours(GetJSONObject(objResultLoop, "opening_hours"))
                    Case "types":
                        dicFlattenedDetails.Add "types", ExtractTypes(GetJSONObject(objResultLoop, "types"))
                    Case "photos":
                        '* NOT YET IMPLEMENTED
                    Case Else
                        Stop
                    End Select

                Next vKeyLoop

                Dim sPlaceID As String
                sPlaceID = VBA.CallByName(objResultLoop, "place_id", VbGet)

                dicTextSearchResults.Add sPlaceID, dicFlattenedDetails

            Next
        End If
    End If



End Function

Private Function ExtractOpeningHours(ByVal objOpeningHours As Object) As String

    Dim vOpenNow As Variant
    vOpenNow = VBA.CallByName(objOpeningHours, "open_now", VbGet)

    Dim bOpenNow As Boolean
    bOpenNow = CBool(vOpenNow)

    Dim objWeekdayText As Object
    Set objWeekdayText = GetJSONObject(objOpeningHours, "weekday_text")

    Dim lLength As Long
    lLength = VBA.CallByName(objWeekdayText, "length", VbGet)

    If lLength > 0 Then

        Dim dicWeekdaysKeys As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set dicWeekdaysKeys = GetScriptEngine.Run("getKeyValues", objWeekdayText)

        Stop
    End If

    ExtractOpeningHours = VBA.IIf(bOpenNow, "open", "closed")

End Function

Private Function ExtractTypes(ByVal objTypes As Object) As String

    Dim lLength As Long
    lLength = VBA.CallByName(objTypes, "length", VbGet)

    Dim dicTypes As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicTypes = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim lLoop As Long
    For lLoop = 0 To lLength - 1
        Dim sTypeLoop As String
        sTypeLoop = VBA.CallByName(objTypes, CStr(lLoop), VbGet)
        dicTypes.Add sTypeLoop, 0

    Next lLoop

    ExtractTypes = VBA.Join(dicTypes.Keys, "|")

End Function



Private Function TestNearbySearch() As Boolean

    Dim dicNearbySearchResults As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicNearbySearchResults = NearbySearch(sKey, sSEVENOAKS_LATITUDE_LONGITUDE, 500, "restaurant")

    Debug.Assert dicNearbySearchResults.Exists("Subway")
    Debug.Assert dicNearbySearchResults.Item("Subway") = "ChIJ_yoN0_tN30cRnjjjqftbnSw"

    TestNearbySearch = True

End Function


Public Function NearbySearch(ByVal sAPIKey As String, ByVal sLocationLatitudeLongitude As String, ByVal lRadius As Long, _
            ByVal sSearchType As String)

    '
    'Tools->References->
    'Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim dicNearbySearchResults As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicNearbySearchResults = New Scripting.Dictionary


    Dim xHTTPRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set xHTTPRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

    xHTTPRequest.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=" & sAPIKey & "&location=" & sLocationLatitudeLongitude & "&radius=" & lRadius & "&type=" & sSearchType

    xHTTPRequest.send

    While xHTTPRequest.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    If Len(xHTTPRequest.responseText) > 0 Then

        Dim objJSON As Object
        Set objJSON = DecodeJsonString(xHTTPRequest.responseText)

        If Not objJSON Is Nothing Then

            Dim sStatus As String
            sStatus = GetJSONPrimitive(objJSON, "status")

            If sStatus = "OK" Then

                Dim objResults As Object
                Set objResults = GetJSONObject(objJSON, "results")

                Dim lLength As Long
                lLength = VBA.CallByName(objResults, "length", VbGet)

                Dim lLoop As Long
                For lLoop = 0 To lLength - 1

                    Dim objResultLoop As Object
                    Set objResultLoop = GetJSONObject(objResults, CStr(lLoop))

                    Dim sName As String
                    sName = VBA.CallByName(objResultLoop, "name", VbGet)

                    Dim sPlaceID As String
                    sPlaceID = VBA.CallByName(objResultLoop, "place_id", VbGet)

                    dicNearbySearchResults.Add sName, sPlaceID

                Next
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Set NearbySearch = dicNearbySearchResults

End Function



Private Function ExtractLatitudeAndLongitude(ByVal objGeometry As Object) As String

    Dim objLocation As Object
    Set objLocation = GetJSONObject(objGeometry, "location")

    Dim sLatitude As String
    sLatitude = VBA.CallByName(objLocation, "lat", VbGet)

    Dim sLongitude As String
    sLongitude = VBA.CallByName(objLocation, "lng", VbGet)

    ExtractLatitudeAndLongitude = sLatitude & "," & sLongitude

End Function


Private Function TestPlaceDetails() As Boolean

    Dim dicPlaceDetails As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicPlaceDetails = PlaceDetails(sKey, sSEVENOAKS_PLACEID)

    Debug.Assert dicPlaceDetails.Keys()(0) = "Location"
    Debug.Assert dicPlaceDetails.Items()(0) = "51.27241,0.190898"
    TestPlaceDetails = True
End Function


Public Function PlaceDetails(ByVal sAPIKey As String, ByVal sPlaceID As String) As Scripting.Dictionary

    'Tools->References->
    'Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim dicPlaceDetails As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicPlaceDetails = New Scripting.Dictionary


    Dim xHTTPRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set xHTTPRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60


    xHTTPRequest.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=" & sAPIKey & "&placeid=" & sPlaceID

    xHTTPRequest.send

    While xHTTPRequest.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    If Len(xHTTPRequest.responseText) > 0 Then

        Dim objJSON As Object
        Set objJSON = DecodeJsonString(xHTTPRequest.responseText)

        If Not objJSON Is Nothing Then


            Dim objResult As Object
            Set objResult = GetJSONObject(objJSON, "result")
            If Not objResult Is Nothing Then
            'If objJSON.hasOwnProperty("result") Then


                Dim objGeometry As Object
                Set objGeometry = GetJSONObject(objResult, "geometry")
                If Not objResult Is Nothing Then

                    Dim objLocation As Object
                    Set objLocation = GetJSONObject(objGeometry, "location")
                    If Not objLocation Is Nothing Then

                        Dim sLatitude As String
                        sLatitude = VBA.CallByName(objLocation, "lat", VbGet)

                        Dim sLongitude As String
                        sLongitude = VBA.CallByName(objLocation, "lng", VbGet)

                        dicPlaceDetails.Add "Location", sLatitude & "," & sLongitude
                    End If

                    dicPlaceDetails.Add "Address", VBA.CallByName(objResult, "formatted_address", VbGet)

                    dicPlaceDetails.Add "Name", VBA.CallByName(objResult, "name", VbGet)

                    If objResult.hasOwnProperty("vicinity") Then
                        dicPlaceDetails.Add "Vicinity", VBA.CallByName(objResult, "vicinity", VbGet)
                    End If

                    Dim objTypes As Object
                    Set objTypes = GetJSONObject(objResult, "types")
                    If Not objTypes Is Nothing Then

                        Dim lTypesLength As Long
                        lTypesLength = VBA.CallByName(objTypes, "length", VbGet)

                        Dim sType0 As String
                        sType0 = VBA.CallByName(objTypes, "0", VbGet)
                        dicPlaceDetails.Add "Type0", sType0
                    End If

                    dicPlaceDetails.Add "PlaceId", sPlaceID

                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Set PlaceDetails = dicPlaceDetails
End Function


Private Function TestAutoComplete() As Boolean

   Dim dicPlacesWithPlaceIds As Scripting.Dictionary
   Set dicPlacesWithPlaceIds = AutoComplete(sKey, "Sevenoaks")

   Debug.Assert dicPlacesWithPlaceIds.Keys()(0) = "Sevenoaks, United Kingdom"
   Debug.Assert dicPlacesWithPlaceIds.Items()(0) = sSEVENOAKS_PLACEID
   TestAutoComplete = True
End Function



Public Function AutoComplete(ByVal sAPIKey As String, ByVal sPlaceText As String) As Scripting.Dictionary

    'Tools->References->
    'Microsoft Scripting Runtime
    Dim dicPlacesWithPlaceIds As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicPlacesWithPlaceIds = New Scripting.Dictionary


    Dim xHTTPRequest As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set xHTTPRequest = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60


    xHTTPRequest.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=" & sAPIKey & "&input=" & sPlaceText & "&sensor=false", False

    xHTTPRequest.send

    While xHTTPRequest.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Wend

    If Len(xHTTPRequest.responseText) > 0 Then


        Dim objJSON As Object
        Set objJSON = DecodeJsonString(xHTTPRequest.responseText)

        If Not objJSON Is Nothing Then

            Dim objPredictions As Object
            Set objPredictions = GetJSONObject(objJSON, "predictions")
            If Not objPredictions Is Nothing Then

                Dim lLength As Long
                lLength = VBA.CallByName(objPredictions, "length", VbGet)

                Dim lLoop As Long
                For lLoop = 0 To lLength - 1

                    Dim objPredictionLoop As Object
                    Set objPredictionLoop = GetJSONObject(objPredictions, CStr(lLoop))

                    Dim sPlaceDescription As String
                    sPlaceDescription = VBA.CallByName(objPredictionLoop, "description", VbGet)

                    Dim sPlaceID As String
                    sPlaceID = VBA.CallByName(objPredictionLoop, "place_id", VbGet)

                    dicPlacesWithPlaceIds.Add sPlaceDescription, sPlaceID
                    'Stop
                Next
                'Stop
            End If

        End If

        'Stop

    End If
    Set AutoComplete = dicPlacesWithPlaceIds
    'Debug.Print xHTTPRequest.responseText


End Function

Private Function NestedDictionaryToGrid(ByVal dicData As Scripting.Dictionary, ByVal dicFieldOrdinals As Scripting.Dictionary) As Variant

    ReDim vRet(1 To dicData.Count + 1, 1 To dicFieldOrdinals.Count)


    Dim vFieldKeyLoop As Variant
    For Each vFieldKeyLoop In dicFieldOrdinals.Keys
        vRet(1, dicFieldOrdinals.Item(vFieldKeyLoop) + 1) = vFieldKeyLoop
    Next

    Dim lRowLoop As Long: lRowLoop = 1

    Dim vDataKeyLoop As Variant
    For Each vDataKeyLoop In dicData.Keys
        lRowLoop = lRowLoop + 1

        Dim dicDetails As Scripting.Dictionary
        Set dicDetails = dicData.Item(vDataKeyLoop)

        For Each vFieldKeyLoop In dicFieldOrdinals.Keys
            vRet(lRowLoop, dicFieldOrdinals.Item(vFieldKeyLoop) + 1) = dicDetails.Item(vFieldKeyLoop)
        Next


    Next vDataKeyLoop


    NestedDictionaryToGrid = vRet

End Function
```

Comment: I no longer use Eval in my code, instead I use Douglas Crockford's library, for reasons see here http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/01/vba-parse-json-safer-with-jsonparse-and.html

Answer (score 4):

I'll clear the easy stuff first, using [Rubberduck 2.0b](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/releases/tag/v2.0b) code inspections:

**Language Opportunities**

- **Prefer `vbNullString` to `""`**: The built-in constant `vbNullString` is a null string pointer taking up 0 bytes of memory, that unambiguously conveys the intent of an empty string.
- **Use of the obsolete `Call` statement**: The `Call` statement is no longer required to call procedures, and only exists in the language to support legacy code that did require it. It can be safely rewritten to the more modern implicit call form.

**Maintainability and Readability Issues**

- **Consider renaming variable `sType0`**: identifier names should indicate what they're used for and should be readable. Avoid numeric suffixes.

**Code Quality Issues**

- Constant `sKEYNAME` is not used. Consider removing it.
- Return value of function `TestAll` is never used. Consider making the function a `Sub` procedure instead.
- Return value of function `ParseTextSearchResponse` is never used. Consider making the function a `Sub` procedure instead.
- Return type of function `ParseTextSearchResponse` is implicitly `Variant` - apparently that function was actually *meant* to be a `Sub`.
- Return value of function `ParseTextSearchResponse` is never assigned. That's it, it's a `Sub` in a `Function` disguise!
- Parameter `vDefaultValue` (in `GetJSONPrimitive`) is implicitly passed by reference. Consider making it explicitly `ByRef`.
- Parameter `vDefaultValue` could be passed by value... unless it could be an array? This inspection result comes up because the parameter isn't assigned a new value in the function's body, but if an array is a valid value for it, then passing it `ByVal` would break the code. If an array isn't a valid value for it, then passing it `ByVal` would make the intent clearer.
- Return type of function `NearbySearch` is implicitly `Variant`. Yet you're assigning it a `Scripting.Dictionary` - why not specify the return type?
- Function `TestAll` is not used. And it's `Private`, too - which makes it essentially unreachable.
- Variable `sTopPrediction` is never used in `EvenBiggerTest`. It's assigned a value, but that value serves no apparent purpose.
- Variable `dicDetails` is never used in `TestTextSearch`. Again it's assigned, but nothing is done with the assigned value.
- Variable `sName` is never used in `ParseTextSearchResponse`. Assigned from a call to `GetJSONPrimitive`, and then nothing.
- Variable `dicWeekdayKeys` is never used in `ExtractOpeningHours`.
- Variable `lTypesLength` is not used either, in `PlaceDetails`.

Not bad at all, I've seen shorter code trigger more inspection results than that!

---

#### Hungarian Notation

Your naming style consistently (good!) uses a heavily discouraged (bad!) Hungarian Notation that encodes a variable's type into its identifier name, which hurts readability (lowercase "L" for "Long"? that's plain evil!) with zero benefits, *especially* since you're declaring variables as close as possible to their usage, so the variable's type is right there in your face anyway - kudos for avoiding the unfortunately too common "wall of declarations" trap!

The "right" way of using Hungarian Notation, is to add *meaningful context* - the name of the type of a variable isn't *meaningful context*. Read [**Making Wrong Code Look Wrong**](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html) on *Joel on Software* for the whole argumentative and examples of "Hungarian Notation done right".

Applied to VBA, I like to use `ByRef` parameters to illustrate. Consider this signature:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(ByVal foo As Integer, ByRef bar As Integer)
```

Ignore the fact that `bar` could be the return value of a `Function` for a moment - this is just an example. What clue does the user of this procedure have that `bar` is really an `out` parameter? None. And we're lucky here, we have explicit `ByVal` and `ByRef` modifiers. Imagine this signature for a procedure that does exactly the same thing:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(foo As Integer, bar As Integer)
```

Ew. Now consider this:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(foo As Integer, outBar As Integer)
```

Oh. An `out` prefix tells us that the second parameter is actually a return value! *That* is a useful prefix. Compare to:

```
Public Sub DoSomething(iFoo As Integer, iBar As Integer)
```

The `i-for-Integer` prefix is totally redundant and useless.

---

`GetScriptEngine` calls `AddCode` 5 times, but once would be enough:

```
Private Function GetScriptEngine() As ScriptControl

    Static scriptEngine As ScriptControl
    Static script As String
    
    If scriptEngine Is Nothing Then
        
        script = GetJavaScriptLibrary("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js") & _
            "function getKeyValues(jsonObj) { " & _
            " var dictionary = new ActiveXObject(""Scripting.Dictionary""); " & _
            " var keys = new Array(); for (var i in jsonObj) { dictionary.add(i,jsonObj[i]); }; return dictionary; } " & _
            "function setKeyValue(jsonObj, key, newItem) { jsonObj[key]=newItem; return jsonObj; }" & _
            "function toVBString(jsonObj) { return JSON.stringify(jsonObj); }" & _
            "function overrideToString(jsonObj) { jsonObj.toString = function() { return JSON.stringify(this); } }"
        
        Set scriptEngine = New ScriptControl
        scriptEngine.Language = "JScript"
        scriptEngine.AddCode script
    End If
    
    Set GetScriptEngine = scriptEngine
    
End Function
```

I have to say I'm ambivalent about `Static` locals: they have that funky smell - a `Static` local could very often just as well be declared at module scope... but then if they're only ever used in one place, what's the point, right?

I think your module is doing too many things, and that you need more objects in your life. Class modules. I'd move that to a `ScriptEngine` class, have the script live there, encapsulated, and holding on to its `ScriptControl` instance, perhaps even encapsulate that as well, and only expose methods that the client code needs to see.

Ignoring the assignment of the function's return value, it's only used in 4 places:

[image: all references to 'GetScriptEngine' - Rubberduck "search results" docked toolwindow]

The members used are `Run` and `Eval` - so yeah, I'd encapsulate it and expose a `Run` and an `Eval` method for the client code to consume, instead of relying on `Static` locals and procedural code.

---

Here's another example of poor naming:

```
Dim vKeyLoop As Variant
For Each vKeyLoop In dicKeys.Keys
```

`vKeyLoop` tells you it's a dictionary key... and that it's used in a loop. Oh and that it's a `Variant`.. If you're going to iterate strings in a `For Each` loop, it needs to be a `Variant` - so again the Hungarian prefix serves no purpose at all. But that's not why it's a bad name: the real question is, **what does the darn key represent?** THAT is what, as a maintainer of that code base, I'd like to be able to infer from the variable's name. I know it's a key because I'm iterating keys. I know it's a loop variable because, well, it's a `For Each` loop variable anyway. And I know it's a `Variant` because it has to be a `Variant` for the `For Each` loop to even compile.

---

Speaking of compiling... `sKey` isn't declared in `BigTest`, which, because of `Option Explicit`, makes the code uncompilable. Ditto in `EvenBiggerTest`, and `TestTextSearch` as well.

---

Speaking of testing... The test code should really be separate from the code it's testing. Pull these methods into their own module, it's urgent!

The tests themselves aren't clear about what the expectations are; they merely output stuff, but we don't know if it's right or if it's wrong until we visually inspect the `ActiveSheet` and interpret the results.

If you could break the coupling with the web API, extract the functionality into a class that only exposes it (the functionality) via an *interface*, then you could implement a mock version of that interface and write (and run!) actual unit tests, which would test all the functionality without ever hitting the web (i.e. they would run in a few milliseconds), and you would have an immediate feedback about exactly which part of the spec you broke with your latest modification - if that sounds interesting, I suggest you take a look at the features page of [Rubberduck's website](http://www.rubberduckvba.com).

> Disclaimer: I'm totally, completely, heavily involved with the Rubberduck project.

Comment: Ok thanks a thorough examination.  I could make rebuttals on many points but it is probably better to move to a meta discussion about code police.   Just a few rebuttals though, the stack overflow (SO) original poster (OP) had his own API key, so sKey was commented out but actually public in another module (not shown) so as not to expose my API key.  Also, I know tests should be in separate modules but I was giving OP a slab of code that they could cut and paste.

Comment: On the meta level is Rubberduck like MZTools which also highlighted unused variables etc.  It sounds like a 'code police' tool which I have had whilst working on very many large systems with millions of lines of code; are the rules configurable?

Comment: Do you have any endorsements from people like Steve Bullen (author of Processional Excel Development)?  He was a mentor of mine when I worked alongside him for two years.

Comment: Not sure it counts as "endorsement", but Mr.Bullen has offered the original VB6 Smart Indenter code to the project; Carlos J.Quintero (author of MZ-Tools) came to our chatroom to congratulate us, and a bunch of MVP's are following us on GitHub and Twitter.

Comment: @SMeaden join [vba rubberducking chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14929/vba-rubberducking) anytime you want to talk about it! =)